# How to center a spinner with cell content view after removing a cell accessory?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview in my storyboard where the prototype cell has a disclosure indicator by default.
When I populate my table I want to remove the indicator only from the last cell AND center a spinner on it.
I'm doing it like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CharacterCell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterCell
        
        if indexPath.row == charactersViewModel.charactersCount - 1 {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            cell.accessoryView = .none
            
            // Spinner
            let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
            spinner.color = .white
            spinner.center = cell.contentView.center
            cell.contentView.addSubview(spinner)
            spinner.startAnimating()
        }
        return cell
    }
```

The problem is that the spinner is offcenter, a little bit to the left, just like if the accessory is still there, but hidden.

I feel maybe I'm missing the lifecycle of a table cell, maybe it's getting the center value of the content view when the accessory is still there, so when it's removed it is offcenter?

I tried on willDisplay as well but the same thing happens.

Any tips on this?

Comment: You should never add sub views in `cellForRow` as it will cause problems when cells are reused. I think a better approach would be to use a different cell subclass for the last row, one that already has the spinner and doesn't have the disclosure accessory.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, I didn't know about that. I'll look into it. Ty friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paulw11 mentioned, I used a second subclass and created another cell prototype in my tableview.

Then when the last position at the table is reached, we can use the second prototype on cellForRowAt.

Here how it is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row >= charactersViewModel.charactersCount - 1 {
            reloadRows(indexPath: indexPath)
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LoadingCharacterCell", for: indexPath) as! LoadingCharacterCell
            cell.startSpinner()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CharacterCell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterCell
            cell.configureCell(charactersViewModel: charactersViewModel, cell: cell, index: indexPath.row)
            return cell
        }
    }

private func reloadRows(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var indexPathList = [IndexPath]()
        indexPathList.append(indexPath)
        charactersTableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathList, with: .automatic)
}
```

And with the reloadRows function, the last cell is updated and removed when the table receives more data.